# Concat double quotes with String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, concatenation

I need a string with double quotes

tried

```
expectedValue = "/""+expectedValue+"/""
```

but did not worked -

Throws below error -

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for "/+expectedValue+":String
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably you mean:

```
expectedValue = "\""+expectedValue+"\""
```

or more in ruby style:

```
expectedValue = "\"#{expectedValue}\""
```

Comment: Would be also great if you accept some answer. To close this question.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `%Q`, or simply `%`

```
expectedValue = %Q{"#{expectedValue}"}

expectedValue = %|"#{expectedValue}"|
```

[Reference: String literals](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)